# How to extract the number from the parent div excluding the text of the child using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I'm trying to fetch the number out the Steam site -> https://store.steampowered.com/about/

Element snapshot:

[image: Steam online users]

Code trials:

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='online_stats']//div[2][@class='online_stat']")).getText().then((text)=>{
  onlinePlayersInGames = text;
});
```

Doing it with this code results in me getting a returned value of:

```
ONLINE
22,099,967
```

Rather than only fetching the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the data for  ***playing now***:

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='online_stat'][./div[@class='online_stat_label gamers_in_game']]")).getText().then((text)=>{
  onlinePlayersInGames = text;
});
```

To extract the data for  ***online***:

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='online_stat'][./div[@class='online_stat_label gamers_online']]")).getText().then((text)=>{
  onlinePlayersInGames = text;
});
```

Comment: It still extracts the wholes elements data meaning:

ONLINE <- From the unnecessary div being the child

21,154,876 <- form the parent div.
I'm only trying to get the number without the unnecessary text.

Comment: How about splitting the text with the newline char (`\n`) as the delimiter before printing?

Comment: As said already, I'm trying to fetch only the number.

Comment: Idk why but it still remains to return the values with a string and number mixed in but it resolved the issue for the later part of the code... I'm comparing the two numbers of players online against players in game.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we cant do that with Selenium for the time being.